# Python: Sorting a dictionary's values whose values are lists of tuples?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, tuples

I would like to sort a dictionary where I have a string key but my values are lists of tuples. For example, imagine we have a dictionary where each person is mapped to their rating of different academic subjects, where d.items() would return:

```
('Person':[("Math",5),("Chemistry",10),("History",2)])
```

Is there any way I can sort the value of each key alphabetically? For example, d['Person'] would now return:

```
('Person':[(Chemistry",10),("History",2),("Math",5)])
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
arr = {
    'Person': [("Math",5),("Chemistry",10),("History",2)]
}

def customKey(a):
    return a[0]

for i in arr.keys():
    arr[i] = sorted(arr[i], key=customKey)

print arr
```